# Updating Realm database and primary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I faced this issue, when i want to update the values in a realm object, uuid is chosen as my primary key as shown below

```
@implementation RLMFMCGProductForm
+ (NSString *)primaryKey
{
    return @"uuid";
}

@end
```

I used this code to update the values:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        NSLog(@"}}}}}}}}}}} %@", form.uuid);
        @try {
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            form.uuid = @"test";
            [realm addOrUpdateObject:form];  // [realm addOrUpdateObject:employeeInfo];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"exception");
            if ([realm inWriteTransaction]) {
                [realm cancelWriteTransaction];
            }
        }
```

The values should be 6 but each time i try to update the number increases to 12, 18 , 24 (a new object is being added not updated)... and the uuid is always printing NULL although i am updating the value to "test" and before handling the error with try/catch the error was : cannot update primary key to an existing value "test" , what am i doing wrong here? is the set for primary key incorrect or the update method?

Comment: it adds a new object as you are assigning a new value to uuid.Alos uuid is a primary key and cannot be given simple strings, you should try using NSUUID!

Comment: what i want is to set value for the first time only and check if the value is different than null after that. is the set method correct?

Comment: use add object for the first time, and later use addOrUpdate

Comment: Did you  enable  realm.update = true ?
If update = true, objects that are already in the Realm will be
            updated instead of added a new.

Comment: how do i enable the update , doesn't the addorupdateObject take care of that part?

Comment: yasser I will help you